# Including file in php which keeps resources intact

Tags: php, include

Let's say I have

**/index.php**

```
<?php include("boxes/boxes.php"); ?>
```

**boxes/boxes.php**

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**boxes/stylesheet.css**

```
body{ background-color: yellow; }
```

The stylesheet won't be included on /index.php, as it'll look in `/` for the stylesheet instead of `boxes/`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not explicitly write in the href

```
<link href="/boxes/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The slash in front of /boxes/stylesheet.css will tell the link to start from the start of the domain. That way it can be used anywhere and it will still work

Comment: Can I do it without changing the path? What if i want the stylesheet to be accessible from both \ and `boxes/`?

Comment: So you want to include the same php file in (for example) /index.php and /boxes/index/php that will detect the stylesheet relevant to the php files location?

Answer (score 0):

Provide an absolute path to your stylesheet file as follow,

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/boxes/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This will solve your issue.

Comment: Can I do it without changing the path? What if i want the stylesheet to be accessible from both \ and `boxes/`?

Comment: Probably not. But if you want to access the same stylesheet from two different location, you can dynamically provide path there.